# Log4J file not printing log data

Tags: java, selenium, caching, logging, log4j

In my Selenium framework i am implementing Log4J library to print test execution log but application.log file is not printing any log. could someone please help me to see why or what's wrong i am doing:

I am doing following:

1) I added 1.2.17 log4J dependency to my pom.xml file
2) Added log4j.properties file to "C:\XXX\IdeaProjects\XXX\AG_CEP_Regression_Testing\src\main\resources\log4j.properties

When I execute the script it generates log file but doesn't print the log data but instead, I see following having printed

```
2019-10-10 11:07:38,039 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_GB", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2019-10-10 11:07:38,042 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en_GB.ftl"): Not found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,043 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en.ftl"): Not found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,044 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent.ftl"): Found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,045 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - Loading template for "Extent.ftl"("en_GB", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/XXX/.m2/repository/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/2.41.2/extentreports-2.41.2.jar!/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/view/Extent.ftl"
2019-10-10 11:07:38,314 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - Couldn't find template in cache for "Extent.ftl"("en_GB", UTF-8, parsed); will try to load it.
2019-10-10 11:07:38,315 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en_GB.ftl"): Not found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,315 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent_en.ftl"): Not found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,315 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - TemplateLoader.findTemplateSource("Extent.ftl"): Found
2019-10-10 11:07:38,316 DEBUG [main] cache:45 - Loading template for "Extent.ftl"("en_GB", UTF-8, parsed) from "jar:file:/C:/XXX/.m2/repository/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/2.41.2/extentreports-2.41.2.jar!/com/relevantcodes/extentreports/view/Extent.ftl"
```

Here are my log4J.properties file contents:

```
log4j.rootCategory=debug, console, file
#log4j.logger.freemarker.cache = DEBUG, file, stdout
# Appender which writes to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender  
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %F %-5p [%t] %c{2} %L - %m%n

# Appender which writes to a file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=application.log

# Defining maximum size of a log file
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10mb 
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout  
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [%t] %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=true
```

This is the last bit of work that I need to incorporate into my framework so any help would highly be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code where you define the logger and put some log message

Comment: Check your logger code that you are importing correct classes(check import package name)

Comment: Thanks, @AlexeyR. for revert back This is how i defined logger and put message ````` Logger log = Logger.getLogger(String.valueOf(ag_base.class)); log.info("Site Launched");````` Also i don't want to define too much message at code level but more interested in printing script execution log

Comment: it might be creating an application.log file in another location. To be sure this is not the problem I would recommend setting a full path for this (ex: /tmp/mylog.log)

Comment: Can you show us also your pox.xml dependency?

Comment: @AlexeyR. - this is the dependency in pom.xml
````
 <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
````

Comment: @vivekdubey - You were right..i was importing import java.util.logging.Logger; instead of import org.apache.log4j.Logger; but having done this problem is still consistent

Comment: Check if there is any conflict with any other logger api like Slf4j etc in any jar.check log file path is correct. You can refer this tutorial Can you try independently with https://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/ tutorial.It should work

Comment: @vivekdubey - It works fine now. Thank you for pasting that tutorial link which is awesome.

Comment: @NikunjPatel Welcome,Its my pleasure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your configuration and here is my advice (since I managed to make it work on my side):

1. Fix your properties file since here `log4j.rootCategory=debug, console, file` you refer to `console` appender but here `log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender` you define `stdout` appender. So that the line would look like `log4j.rootCategory=debug, stdout, file`
2. Make sure you import porper `Logger` class where you log your messages. Check that you are using `import org.apache.log4j.Logger;` but not `import java.util.logging.Logger;` or whatever else.
3. Make sure there are no other log4j configuration files in class path

This is my test code (assuming the property file has been fixed):

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class TestLogging {

    static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestLogging.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Test");
    }

}
```

Here is console output:

```
10-10-2019 14:22:29 TestLogging.java INFO  [main] TestLogging 8 - Test
```

And here is file output:

```
2019-10-10 14:22:29,447  INFO [main] TestLogging:8 - Test
```

Comment: Yes, now it works for me...Many thanks for your time to troubleshoot my issue..